# FindRoot gives strange results when used on an interpolating function with vector output

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I am currently experiencing a problem when I try to use `FindRoot` with an interpolating function that outputs a vector. I have constructed a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

Consider the following function, that parametrizes a circle in the plane.

```
circle[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
```

Suppose you want to find the point at which the x coordinate of the circle equals one half.

```
FindRoot[ circle[t][[1]] - 0.5, {t, 0.1, 0, Pi/2}]
```

Of course, `FindRoot` finds the root:

> ```
> {t -> 1.0472}
> ```

However, sometimes you do not have an exact function, and you need to use an `InterpolatingFunction` instead. The function `circleInterpol` is an interpolation of $100$ points sampled from the circle. Although the interpolation of lists of the type `{ t, {x,y}}` is not considered in the reference, *Mathematica* does not issue any warnings and plotting using `ParametricPlot` works fine.

```
circleInterpol = Interpolation[ Table[{t, circle[t]}, {t, 0, Pi/2, Pi/200}]]
ParametricPlot[{circle[t], circleInterpol[t]}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

However, when I try to use `FindRoot` in the same way as before:

```
FindRoot[circleInterpol[t][[1]] - 0.5, {t, 0.1, 0, Pi/2}]
```

but with circle replaced by `circleInterpol`, I get a completely different (and obviously wrong) result:

> ```
> {t -> 0.5}
> ```

`FindRoot` does not issue any warnings at this point.

Changing the syntax to (I realize that `{0.5, 0.1}` is not a point on the circle, but since you take the first part anyway, this should not matter.)

```
FindRoot[(circleInterpol[t] - {0.5, 0.1})[[1]], {t, 0.1, 0, Pi/2}]
```

issues the warning:

> ```
> FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in
> FindRoot[(circleInterpol[t] - {0.5, 0.1})[[1]], { t, 0.1, 0, Pi/2}]. >>
> ```

Replacing the interpolating function by the exact function still gives the correct result.

So it seems to me that something is going wrong with the combination of `FindRoot` and `InterpolatingFunction`. An obvious solution to the problem is to construct two interpolating functions; one for each coordinate (`x` and `y`). Although this would solve the problem, I do not understand why this extra step is necessary.

Could someone help me to understand what is going wrong here?

Comment: Try evaluating `circleInterpol[t]` and `circleInterpol[t][[1]]` and you'll see what's going wrong.  It won't give you the result you expect if `t` is a symbol, only if `t` is a number.  Solution: define `fun[t_?NumericQ] := circleInterpol[t][[1]]` and use that.  Side note: don't build the interpolating function from exact numbers if you need good performance.  Please read this too: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/12

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for the quick reply and for recognizing the question as a duplicate. I understand that the problem is in the function evaluation. Because of this, it seems that the extra option `Evaluated -> False` in `FindRoot` also works.